# Service invoked too many times for one day: email

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I am trying the [Code](https://script.google.com/d/MT7dWKBdIiIrlPFhwYXDUalz_Zwk5FNSL/edit?mid=ACjPJvFszEoOdMfGudPk0DTUPOcabf4BIWmZjjPcjOYrs22PEgyiQTLlvj0wRQVrRsulhYDVm-254SL6jqg-iu3p0qsvLz0F222FqgvMHS5laczORGyIQmB8EA_g05LmeAOwZSlxUmh4Ofs&uiv=2) to send an email on every form submission using Google Apps Script.

Could you please see the code and let me know how to fix the below error

> Google Script: Service invoked too many times for one day: email. (line 39, file "Code")

Comment: You can add your code directly in your questions, please do it for better chance of getting help.

Comment: Your link is not public but yes we would prefer if you would post it into your question.

Comment: Obviously,  you're hitting quotas. There's nothing you can do except reducing the number of times you send email.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question doesn't contain the code and the linked code repository isn't available anymore.

Comment: @Oleg This is not a good question

Comment: Yep, I already noticed... This overlooked the code link at first

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing you can do when you **hit quota limits** except for reducing the number of calls to the service you are using.

Google provides info solely on an informational basis and does not provide guarantees that they will stay the same, so please always consult the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) beforehand.

Depending on your type of **GSuite account edition** you will be able to invoke more or less of the Google Apps Script services.

When you hit the limits you will get an error depending on the service you are using. You could have errors for too many daily invocations, exceeding rate-limit or service using too much computer time for one day...

I hope this can help you understand better your issue if it presents to you again in the future or something related to it.

Comment: This is now resolved. Thank you so much for all your help.